# Django: Having arbitrary file access models

Tags: python, django

Seems like a really simple issue I am having, but for whatever reason I cannot get an arbitrary file i create within a Django app to access my models/compile.

```
analytics/
   analytics/
     settings.py
     etc...
   mapper/
     models.py
     views.py
     filetoDothings.py
```

I would like "fileToDoThings.py" do things with my models, but when i put even a few simple lines of code in filetodothings, and try to import the models i get the following error: "Requested setting DEFAULT_INDEX_TABLESPACE, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure()"

A lot of searching has led me to find answers similar to this:

```
sys.path.append("path/toproject")
os.environ["DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE"] = "myApp.settings"
from django.contrib.auth.models import ModelName
```

This worked, but only when i moved the arbitrary file to the outermost "analytics" directory. Even though I got this to work, it never quite seemed to make sense to me/seemed like a lot of work to get a file to access models in the same directory.

So what I am trying to do now is the following, in filetoDothings.py:

```
from models import Addresses
usaMapPoints = Addresses.objects.filter(countryCode='US').order_by("-frequency")[:25]
print(usaMapPoints)
```

For "messing around" purposes, I want to call "python filetodothings.py" and have it print the results in the console. But ultimately Im just trying ot get my head around how to create a file that can be automated later on.

I have seen the code for another Django app and someone was able to do exactly this.

Am I missing something really simple?

Answer (score 2):

> I would like "fileToDoThings.py" do things with my models

To do arbitrary operations from the command line, write a new [Django management command](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/).

You write your ‘lorem_ipsum.py’ module within a particular app, placing it a `fooapp/management/commands/lorem_ipsum.py`. Write it to define a command as per the documentation above.

Then you can invoke that as a management command: `python3 -m manage lorem_ipsum`.

---

> Am I missing something really simple?

Simple, yes; obvious, no.

Django is a framework, not a library. The difference has been characterised by saying that with a library, you write code that calls the library; with a framework, you write code that gets called by the framework.

In other words, the way to get things done in a framework is to find the places where your code fits, and write it to fit those places.

Answer (score 0):

looks like you need create command

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/